# ffmpeg - Get max Y value of video stream

Tags: ffmpeg

is it possible to get the max Y value (of a pixel) of a video stream assuming the video is in YCbCr or YUV ?

if so, what would be the process ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does max Y mean - frame containing pixel with highest Y or frame with highest average Y?

Comment: @Gyan: I meant the max Y value of a pixel, I've updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: signalstats filter will provide that info per-frame.

Comment: can you write an example (how to parse each frame of a stream and then use signalstats) as an answer ? I'll gladly accept it ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ffmpeg -i video -vf "signalstats,metadata=print:key=lavfi.signalstats.YMAX:file=logfile:direct=1" -an -f null -`

This will print the maximum luma value seen in each frame to `logfile`.